# How to use a Variable from a python script in gitlab variables?

Tags: python, variables, gitlab, containers, buildah

I am running a python code, which has few variables. The script is running inside a container through buildah, which is running in a gitlab stage.

`buildah run $containerId`

I want to extract a variable from that python script and use it in another stage of gitlab.

I tried to extract by defining variable in the command like this -

`buildah run $containerId --env VAR1=$VAR1`

`echo $VAR`

but i am not getting any output. Can anybody help me with this.